# Bad decrypt error whenever I open a shell

Tags: macos, openssl, macos-high-sierra, libressl

I am using macOS version 10.13.5 and whenever I open a new shell I get this error printed to shell:

> bad decrypt
>
> 140735978677192:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:529:

Openssl version is : LibreSSL 2.2.7

Here is the related command that cause problem :

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -in ~/.foo/bar/credentials -k $cred_enc_key
```

Maybe this code helps : [libressl-portable related source code](https://github.com/libressl-portable/openbsd/blob/8344ab14a2f6b4aa84db9a7076626906bfbc9645/src/lib/libcrypto/evp/evp_enc.c#L526)

Also this post on Stackoverflow : [two different openssl versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49589140/3554537)

Comment: Something in one of your shell startup files (~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile, or ~/.bashrc) is trying to decrypt something, and it's failing. Without knowing what it's trying to decrypt, why, where the file it's decrypt came from, etc, I don't think anyone will be able to help you. Take a look at those startup files (whichever exist), and find out more about what's going on.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I have checked all these files. the only suspicious part in .bash_profile which is related to brew is:      

if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
. $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion 
fi

Comment: *Some*thing has to be running openssl. You might try adding `set -x` at the beginning of ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile (whichever exists), and see what's happening when the error appears.