# Decrypting file created with old openssl version

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have an archive created with OpenSSL 1.0.lt version (May 2016). I am able to decrypt it by using the same version with command `openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in file.enc -out clear.zip -pass pass:MY_KEY`. I am not able to decrypt it using a more recent OpenSSL version.

When I try the same command with OpenSSL version 1.1.1 I get an error message: `digital envelope routines: EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c.610`. Do I have to modify the command?

Comment: OpenSSL used MD5 as default digest in earlier versions, from OpenSSL version 1.1.0 SHA256 is applied as default digest. Try to set the digest explicitly with `-md md5` when decrypting with the newer version. As context: the digest is used in key derivation when a password is passed.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39637388/880188